# perlbrew perl installation, is build folder necessary after install?

Tags: perl-module, perlbrew, perl

I installed perl5 using perlbrew using the following command

```
perlbrew install -v perl-5.18.2 -Dusethreads -n --as perl-5.18.2_WITH_THREADS
```

After the installation, I find that this folder "~/perl5/perlbrew/build" takes 182MB. Is this folder necessary? If not could I remove that?

Comment: Rule of thumb: rename it.  If it doesn't break anything after a few days, delete it.

Comment: I could do that, but it still leaves a possibility of me not running into an issue in the few days I wait, but some issue could have been created due to this action right. Is there a way to know concretely if this folder is useful or not after install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessary, and you can safely remove it.

Comment: You can also nuke the tarballs in `dists`. (These are kept around to save `perlbrew` from having to download them again.)

Comment: Oh...Thanks a lot. I've been trying to optimize disk space used by a perl docker image. Deleting ./build released a whopping 182MB and ./dists another 14MB for perl 5.18.2. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4):

If you run

```
perlbrew clean
```

that will automatically cleanup the build and dist directories.